# Is there decent way to blur the background of a window?

Tags: android, view, blur

Let's say it's a popup window centred in screen.

First way came to mind was take a screenshot of the activity(UI) before the window pops up, blur the bitmap with fast blur and set the background.

However, I gave up this idea for my project, because capture the screen needs activity reference.

A item of a RecyclerView(which embedded in a fragment), triggers the popup window. The onClick method is bound in its adapter. When triggered a popup, the onClick must do the capture screen stuff. However, it refuses to do this job.

```
item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    // Capture screen, blur it, set it to the background of popup window
});
```

The project is using dataBinding, so the adapter is called in this way:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:data")
public static void setData(RecyclerView recyclerView, List<ItemData> data){
    if (data != null) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemsAdapter(recyclerView.getContext(), data));
    }
}
```

Now you got the idea why couldn't capture the screen, for there is no way pass an activity reference. **By the way, even if there is way, I don't think it is good idea to pass an activity reference to an adapter, which may cause OOM.**

Later, I tried many way for blurring the background of popup window. They just failed. I found Instagram has this feature(android version). That's what I want.

I wonder if I need to reconstruct my project just to expose the adapter and make it take an activity as a parameter.

Or there is some decent way to do this kind of job, not just capture the screen.

Comment: what do you need `"activity reference"` for? all you need is a windows's root decor view

Comment: @pskink How could get the decor view if you aren't in activity 's context

Comment: so what context are you in? you have `RecyclerView`, dont you? so get its root view

Comment: The recyclerview embeds in a fragment which is a view pager. I am afraid you can't get its root view

Comment: check `android.view.View` documentation then

Comment: I checked it. Sorry for my ignorance. It sure works. Thank you. You can answer it and be accepted. Thanks